# JQuery Undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two hours think what is the fail with my code. It's throws error in:

```
  $('form').validate({
```

The error that shows is:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I'm getting crazy with this.

This is all my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0050)http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/ -->
<html lang="es">

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>CoolFitness</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsiveslides.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css">
              <link href="css/jquery-letterfx.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,900,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body class="mybody">
 <div class="divHead" class="container" style="z-index:9999;">


    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">

          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>

            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

          </button>

          <div style="width: 171px;">

          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">ArqOS Scheduler</a></div>

        </div>

        <div id="nav-main" class="collapse navbar-collapse">

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

            <li class="inactive"><a href="#" onclick="#">Nodes</a></li>

            <li class="inactive"><a href="#" onclick="#">Tasks</a></li>

          </ul>
<button type="button" class="susc btn btn-primary">Suscribirse</button>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->

      </div>

    </div>
    </div>
     <div class="divBody" class="container">

    <div id="content" class="container-fluid">



      <div id="message" class="row-fluid hidden"></div>

    <div id="page" class="row-fluid"><div class="page-header"><div id="dialog" style="display: none;" title="Task detail">

    <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="row-fluid" style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="firstname">Nome:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Insira o seu nome próprio" name="firstname" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="lastname">Apelido:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">€</span>
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Insira o seu apelido" name="lastname" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>    </div>
    </div>
  </div>


<div class="jumbotron img-rounded">

  <h1 id="Hellow" class="titlejb">Bienvenido a CoolFitness</h1>

  <p>Si crees que debes mejorar tu estilo de vida y apariencia física has llegado al sitio correcto. En esta página web podrás encontrar los últimos consejos e información acerca del fitness, dietas, estilos de vida, planes y ejercicios de automejora, los mejores alimentos antioxidantes, una guía para perder peso, ganar músculo o... ¡las dos cosas! Para que no te pierdas nada también tienes la opción de suscribirte por RSS, correo electrónico, Twitter o Facebook.</p>
    <p>Recuerda, siempre podrás conseguir resultados si mejoras día a día, paso a paso, no puedesp pretender mejorar de la noche a la mañana, todo requiere esfuerzo y nadie dijo que fuera sencillo. Como decía Gabriela Mistral: </p><p style="font-style: italic;">"Donde haya un árbol que plantar, plántalo tú. Donde haya un error que enmendar, enmiéndalo tú. Donde haya un esfuerzo que todos esquivan, hazlo tú. Sé tú el que aparta la piedra del camino."</p>

  <p><a id="Learnmore" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Learn more</a></p>

</div></div>





<div class="container fluidwidth" style="width: 100%">



    <div class="row" id="rowthumblarge">

        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-7 col-xs-5">            

            <div class="thumbnail">

                <div class="caption">

                    <h4>Los mejores ejercicios de Fitness</h4>

                    <p>Descubre los ejercicios más duros que te harán sudar sangre, ¡hasta ganar músculo y perder grasa al mismo tiempo!.</p>                

                </div>

                <img src="img/tb1.jpg" alt="...">

            </div>

      </div>



        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-7  col-xs-5">            

            <div class="thumbnail">

                <div class="caption">

                    <h4>¿Saludable o no saludable?</h4>

                    <p>¡Un divertido juego para comprobar tus conocimientos de nutrición!</p>                

                </div>

                <img src="img/tb2.jpg" alt="¿Saludable o no saludable?">

            </div>

      </div>



        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-7 col-xs-5">            

            <div class="thumbnail">

                <div class="caption">

                    <h4>Thumbnail Headline 3</h4>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus hendrerit, sem at viverra porttitor, velit arcu accumsan nibh, sed iaculis justo urna non massa.</p>                

                </div>

                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-400-300-4.jpg" alt="...">

            </div>

      </div>


        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-7 col-xs-5">            

            <div class="thumbnail" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="¡Échale un vistazo solo si eres muy valiente!">

                <div class="construction">

                   <h4>En construccion</h4>


                </div>

                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-400-300-8.jpg" alt="...">

            </div>

      </div>        



  </div>



    <!-- Slideshow 4 -->

    <div class="callbacks_container">

      <ul class="rslides" id="slider4">

        <li>

          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-400-300-9.jpg" alt="Thumbnail Headline 1" />

          <p class="caption">Thumbnail Headline 1</p>

        </li>

        <li>

          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-400-300-2.jpg" alt="Thumbnail Headline 2" />

          <p class="caption">Thumbnail Headline 2</p>

        </li>

        <li>

          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-400-300-4.jpg" alt="Thumbnail Headline 3" />

          <p class="caption">Thumbnail Headline 3</p>

        </li>

          <li>

          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-400-300-8.jpg" alt="Thumbnail Headline 4" />

          <p class="caption">Thumbnail Headline 4</p>

        </li>

      </ul>

    </div>







    </div><!-- /.container -->



 <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
          <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
              <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/responsiveslides.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-letterfx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
    });

function closemenu() {
   $(function(){ 
     var navMain = $("#nav-main");

     navMain.on("click", "a", null, function () {
         navMain.collapse('hide');
     });
 });
}


$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('form').validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 15,
                required: true
            },
            lastname: {
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 15,
                required: true
            }
        },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        },
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorClass: 'help-block',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
    });


 $('#btnSave').click(function (){

    fModalEstadoInicial();
});

function fModalEstadoInicial(){
    $('#btnSave')[0].disabled = true;
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "close" );
}

$("#btnClose").click(function () {
    fModalEstadoInicial();
});
$( "#dialog" ).on( "dialogclose", function( event, ui ) { 
    bluroff();
});
function bluroff() {
   $( ".divBody" ).removeClass( "notouch blur" );
   $( ".divHead" ).removeClass( "notouch blur" );
   $( ".footerrow" ).removeClass( "notouch blur" );
   $( ".ui-dialog" ).removeClass( "scale" );
   $( ".divBody" ).addClass( "bluroff" );
   $( ".divHead" ).addClass( "bluroff" );
   $( ".footerrow" ).addClass( "bluroff" );
}

function bluron() {
    $( ".divBody" ).addClass( "notouch blur" );
    $( ".divHead" ).addClass( "notouch blur" );
    $( ".footerrow" ).addClass( "notouch blur" );
    $( ".ui-dialog" ).addClass( "scale" );       
    $( ".divBody" ).removeClass( "bluroff" );
    $( ".divHead" ).removeClass( "bluroff" );
    $( ".footerrow" ).removeClass( "bluroff" );
}
$(".susc").click(function () {
    var checks =  $(this).siblings().find('input').is(':checked');
    currentPanel=$(this).closest('.panel')
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    bluron();
    });

     $(function () {


    $('.titlejb').letterfx({"fx":"grow fall fly-left","backwards":false,"timing":100,"fx_duration":"1000ms","letter_end":"restore","element_end":"restore"})


      // Slideshow 4

      $("#slider4").responsiveSlides({

        auto: true,

        pager: false,

         nav: false,

        speed: 500,

        namespace: "callbacks",

        before: function () {

          $('.events').append("<li>before event fired.</li>");

        },

        after: function () {

          $('.events').append("<li>after event fired.</li>");

        }

      });



    });


    $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();    



    $('.thumbnail').hover(

        function(){

            $(this).find('.caption').fadeIn(250); //.fadeIn(250)

        },

        function(){

            $(this).find('.caption').fadeOut(250); //.fadeOut(205)

        }

    );





});

</script>
</div>
 <div class="footerrow">         <div class="col-sm-4">

           <p class="info"> Copyright 2014 ©  Indra </p>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-8 text-right">

           <p class="info2"> Acerca de | Contacto | Encontrar trabajo | Política de privacidad </p> 

        </div>



</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code does not include `jquery.validate.js`, hence it is undefined.

Comment: You need the plug-in as Rory said: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jquery validator for that but you need to add jquery.validate.js and jquery.form.js file for that. after including validator file define your validation something like this. (you can include it from below) :-

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#formID").validate({
    rules :{
        "data[User][name]" : {
            required : true
        }
    },
    messages :{
        "data[User][name]" : {
            required : 'Enter username'
        }
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks and now i put the checkbox required too but i want to put a message like "you must need to check at least 1 checkbox..) how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

As  Rory McCrossan said:

looks like you are missing the validation lib, you can include from here:

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js